# Error:Cause: zip file is empty Android studio 0.8.14

Tags: android, android-studio, zip

Error:Cause: zip file is empty

Can you help me please solve this problem?
i am starting to learn android studio now. if you can give me specific instructions  what to do step by step it would help me very much.

and also i nead instructions , how to create a new project and run it, i want to see the simulator..

Answer (score 5):

I have the same error in my project.(Android Studio 1.1.0, Windows 7) And after I do below, it works:

I find that in 
C:\Users\{USER NAME}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\{hashCode}\
the gradle-2.2.1-all.zip is not exist(or its size is 0Byte).

So I download gradle-2.2.1-all.zip from: 
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
And I place it in C:\Users\{USER NAME}\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\{hashCode}\

I hope it can help you.